# Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP and not familiar with many of its rules, so this could possibly be a stupid question.

I have a database with top level categories and subcategories combined into one table. I want to first print out all the top-level categories, and then printout the subcategories associated with that category.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once "/mysqli_connect.php";

$categories0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'category'");


mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap" class="animate">

<?php 

while ($categories = mysqli_fetch_array($categories0, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $catecory_name = $categories['category'];
    echo '
    <div class="content">
    <div class="content_container no_padding">
    <div class="content_container header">
    <p>'.$categories['category'].'</p>
    </div>
    ';

    $subcategories0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'subcategory'");

    while ($subcategories = mysqli_fetch_array($subcategories0, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $subcategories['category'];
    //mysqli_free_result($subcategories0);
    }

    echo '
    </div>
    </div>
    ';

}

 ?>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the connection script:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', '*');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWD', '*');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '*');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '*');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME);

if(!$conn){
    die('Database connection error');
}

echo '<!-- Connected to database -->'

?>
```

It returns the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
```

When both queries are above the doctype everything is fine, but when the second query is below the doctype the error occurs.

The first query always runs without problems, it is the second one that returns the error.

I can't seem to figure out what is going on, if anyone can help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code that opens the connection to the database?

Comment: WHy not you remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your code and try!!

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens yes. The first query ran fine, it's just the second one.

Comment: Did you try to use `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: @Saty I tried, it had no effect.

Comment: Did you close the first while loop?

Comment: @Saty Yes I understood you checked my comment.

Comment: @a3ey i check check his code and found he forget to close while loop and your are also right.

Comment: @Saty Sry mate.. Not in a good mood today.

Comment: @a3ey its happens some day...:D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forget to close your while loop. check comment in line where you need to close it.

```
<?php
$categories0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'category'");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
while ($categories = mysqli_fetch_array($categories0, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {// need to close your loop

$catecory_name = $categories['category'];
echo '
<div class="content">
<div class="content_container header">
<p>'.$categories['category'].'</p>
</div>
';
}// close here
$subcategories0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'subcategory'");
// The above line is where the error occurs 

while ($subcategories = mysqli_fetch_array($subcategories0, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $subcategories['category'];

}


?>
```

**UPDATED**

Remove close connection from top because after it your query will not execute. Your connection variable is vanished after your connection is closed.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once "/mysqli_connect.php";

$categories0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'category'");


?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Today I have phased the same problem. But There is little mistake that you did in code.

You are trigger select statement this:

See. You are now closing the connection with mysqli_close($conn);

and then in while loop you are fetching data. If connection has been closed then how can php take data from mysql table?

Just remove mysqli_close($conn); statement and run.

In the last line you can put this code. After all the operation.

Comment: This is why I love Stackoverflow, fatigue had settled in and I accidentally closed a connection while I was still using it. Your answer snapped me out of stupidity and back to reality.